# Можно ли в mysql консоли после нажатия enter вернуться на линию выше и работать с той строкой?

Tags: консоль, mysql

Можно ли в mysql консоли после нажатия enter вернуться на линию выше и работать с той строкой? И если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: стрелочка вверх?

Comment: Вопрос, работает ли "стрелочка вверх" в виндовой командной стоке (я просто не в курсе)

Comment: работает :)

Comment: @Gorets стрелочка вверх копирует в эту строку значение предыдущей строки

Comment: мы про командрую строну винды говорим? тогда наверно - нельзя, потому что ентер - исполняет команду, а не переходит на новую строку и бегайть по строке можно только стрелочками лево/право

Comment: эх... жаль

Comment: можно делать copy/paste - правой кнопкой по выделеному тексту/в новой строке

Answer (score 1):

«вернуться на линию» — что бы ни означали эти слова, судя по всему, невозможно.

а вот пролистать историю команд, если она сохраняется, можно — нажимая (неоднократно) кнопку «стрелка вверх». и, в обратном направлении — «стрелку вниз».